# Is drizzle a contracts lib?

Tags: contract-development, truffle, truffle-contract, ganache, drizzle

I'm researching about smart contracts, and been seeing a lot of truffleframework, ganache and drizzle. In the other hand, only found broad descriptions of those tools:

["Drizzle is a collection of front-end libraries that make writing dapp front-ends easier and more predictable"](https://truffleframework.com/docs/drizzle/getting-started)

Still not sure of what is what in this framework, can anyone clarify that please?

- Is Ganache a private/local blockchain?
- Is Drizzle a browser to blockchain hook? Or something to work with solidity?
- Is the Truffle a wrapper for those two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is Ganache a private/local blockchain?

yes

- Is Drizzle a browser to blockchain hook?

No

- Or something to work with solidity?

yes. Drizzle is a framework that help you to easily build the front end part in your Dapp (similar at some extent to a CMS)

- Is the Truffle a wrapper for those two?

in my opinion the term wrapper isn't suitable, rather Truffle can be considered as a toolbox or a suite offering you the prementioned tools.

As you notice all their names are similar (chocolate or cake names)

Answer (score 2):

Ganache is a private/local blockchain. Drizzle is what truffle calls an **abstraction** so that you can focus on your dapp without having to deal with the front end as much. Truffle is a framework that works well with the other two. It has web3 integrated into it and makes testing a lot easier as well.

Answer (score 0):

drizzle is a redux store that exports objects like drizzle and drizzleState to any component that uses DrizzleContex or that get's the objects via props.

The trick of drizzle is that it organizes the communication with the blockchain and syncs it to its redux store. So you only need to communicate with the store throug cacheCall, cacheSend and so on.

So that makes life much more easier